# Adding on change event to dropdownlist declared with a select class

Tags: asp.net, onchange

Issue adding on change event to a control.

I currently have a page that uses this in the aspx page to declare a dropdownlist

```
 <select class="dropdownPhase" />
```

I am trying to add a on change event to the above dropdownlist something like what i did on another page. the problem is i cannot change it to be declared like a normal dropdownlist is it possible to add the onchange event?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownPhase"  onchange="ApplicationRecording.prototype.onPhaseChange1(this,$(this).closest('tr'));"  />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the client-side event to the DropDownList in code:

```
dropdownPhase.Attributes["onChange"] = "someJavaScriptFunction();";
```

You might have to set AutoPostBack to False.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can i add this on change event on client side?

Comment: +1 Not only you can add.., but you should add to use onchange property

Comment: Not directly, no. I believe this is the best way. You can try to do it with JQuery, or maybe by using some kind of script injection like RegisterClientScriptBlock (not client side either), but this is easy enough. If you are worried about your control not having the script before your page load, try setting it in a stage like "OnPreRender".